# Change Select Options using Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have several dropdowns:

```
<select class="drop">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>

<select class="drop">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

How can I change the selected option to `<option value="2">Value 2</option>` using the selector class `drop` via Protoype JS?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little unclear exactly what you are asking but I think you are asking how to set the second value to the selected value in the drop down.

here's the one-liner

```
$$('.drop').invoke('setValue','2');
```

or

```
$$('.drop').each(function(dropdown){
    dropdown.setValue('2');
});
```

You need to use the `setValue()` method to handle weirdness with how the dropdown is implemented across browsers.

Bonus : you can use `setValue(['1','2'])` to set multiple values in a multiple select dropdown